# Not understanding why code isn't producing desired answer

Tags: c++

The assignment I've been given is asking me to find out how many trees can be put in a certain length and how much total space they'd take up including the required space between the trees. Thanks to some help I've been able to get the tree total correct, but the total space taken up is incorrect. What can I do to fix this.

input is: length = 10, TRadius = .5, ReqSpace = 3

desired output is: TreeTot = 2
Total space should be 1.57

Actual output is: TreeTot = 2 Total Space is 6.1

Here is the code I'm using.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const double PI = 3.14;

int main()
{
    double length;
    double TRadius;
    double ReqSpace;
    int TreeTot = 0;

    cout << "enter length of yard: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout << "enter radius of a fully grown tree: ";
    cin >> TRadius;
    cout << "required space between fully grown trees: ";
    cin >> ReqSpace;

    while  (length > TRadius * 2 + ReqSpace) {
        TreeTot += 1;
        length -= (TRadius * 2) + ReqSpace;
    }
     cout << "The total space taken up is "; 
     cout << setprecision(2) << TreeTot * TRadius * PI + ReqSpace << endl; 
     cout << "The total amount of trees is ";
     cout << TreeTot;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please include input, output and expected output in the question (and perhaps remove the rant about your course, it isnt relevant for the question)

Comment: The lines `TreeTot + 1; length - (TRadius * 2) + ReqSpace;` just throw away the results - you need to save them somewhere if you want to use them

Answer (score 7):

These two lines:

```
        TreeTot + 1;
        length - (TRadius * 2) + ReqSpace;
```

are valid statements, but they're just expressions. You calculate a value, but don't do anything with it. `TreeTot + 1`... and then what? You need to assign the calculated value to something. Presumably you're wanting to increase the `TreeTot` and decrease the `length`. Just assign the values like so:

```
        TreeTot = TreeTot + 1;
        length = length - (TRadius * 2) + ReqSpace;
```

Or  use the shorthand for modifying and assigning the result to the same value:

```
        TreeTot += 1;
        length -= (TRadius * 2) + ReqSpace;
```

Your answer will probably still be wrong because the if-statement only runs once - you never tell it you want it to do the code within multiple times. If you change the `if` to a `while` then the code will loop until `length` is too small to satisfy the condition.

Comment: This solved the math not happening, thanks a ton, however the total space taken up is still wrong, but I assume that's me not ordering my math correctly. I'll continue trying to troubleshoot. Again, thanks a ton.

Comment: @Prometheus Glad it helped. I am not sure how you reached your expected answer. Can you put the formula in the question? Plugging in the values to the formula in your code, `TreeTot * TRadius * PI + ReqSpace`, produces exactly the correct number for me: `2 * 0.5 * 3.14 + 3 = 6.14`.

Comment: It isn't something that I determined to be the correct answer, it's what the assignment told me was the correct answer, and I don't know what formula they're wanting me to use, I have to interpret. I'll see if I can't find out what formula is being used and I will message my teacher for insurance. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.